# Lombok with default-constructor

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I have a class like this:

```
@Service("aSpringService")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @NonNull
    private final Member1 m1;

    @NonNull
    private final Member2 m2;

    @NonNull
    private final Member3 m3;

}
```

The constructor will be created by Lombok and at runtime, spring will inject the members into the constructor.
Now I need a setup-method and got stuck with lombok. It seems, that Lombok cannot call something self-written.

### What I want

I want a new parameter for the Lombok-Annotation like `useDefaultConstructor`. When this parameter is present, then the automated-code (from Lombok) will call a parameter-less constructor, which I can write for my own.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}), useDefaultConstructor = true)
// Note the "useDefaultConstructor = true" 
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @NonNull
    private final Member1 m1; 

    private ServiceImpl() {
        //some self-written setup-code
    }
}
```

Generated class:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    private final Member1 m1;

    // This constructor is not generated by lombok
    private ServiceImpl() {
        //some self-written setup-code
    }

    // Constructor generated by lombok
    @Autowired
    public ServiceImpl(Member1 m1) {
       this(); // <- only created when "useDefaultConstructor" is present
       this.m1 = m1;
    }
}
```

### The question

Is there a way to do this with lombok?
Iam to lazy to write the constructor for my own (and change it everytime, when a need a new spring-member).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried Spring `@PostConstruct` annotation?

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // setup-code
}
```

It is a part of Spring's [beans lifecycle management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-nature).

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do.

Comment: You can find more about Beans Lifecycle in [this chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-nature) of Spring Documentation